# net stop "service" not splitting log lines

Tags: batch-file, logging, service, cmd

A batch is writing info about stopped services into a log file with timestamps.

I noticed some of the steps of execution of a **net stop** *"service"* command split the outcome on different lines.

```
echo|set /p=%date%-%time% >> Stop.log & net stop "Service1" >> Stop.log
```

Actual **Stop.log** result:

```
05/04/2019- 9:32:28.87  Service1 is stopping.
Service1 service was stopped successfully.
```

Expected **Stop.log** result:

```
05/04/2019- 9:32:28.87  Service1 is stopping.
05/04/2019- 9:34:21.23  Service1 service was stopped successfully.
```

Comment: You're providing `%DATE%` and `%TIME%`, only once; `Net Stop` appears to be outputting `2` lines. How do you expect to inject the date and time half way through the output from another command? You haven't attempted to do so, so I don't see how, you can expect `Stop.log` to output it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

force `net stop` to return a single line (more accurate: combine all output lines into one):

```
@echo off
(<nul set /p"=%date%-%time% "
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('net stop "Service1"') do <nul set /p "=%%a "
  echo/
)>> Stop.log
```

(Note to anyone who wants to try without stopping services: instead of `net stop "Service1"` try `dir /b`)

To *keep* the output as several lines, but prepend date and time to *each* line:

```
 @echo off
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('net stop "Service1"') do echo %date%-%time% %%a >> Stop.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the output of `net stop` and precede `!date!-!time!` to each line. Ensure to have [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled for that (otherwise you will get the same date and time for every line):

```cmd
>> "Stop.log" (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('net stop "Service1"') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo/!DATE!-!TIME! !LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Note that blank lines returned by `net stop` become lost due to `for /F`. So are lines that begin with a semicolon as this is the default for the `eol` character of `for /F`.